# How to create docker image with dockerfile using cmd

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have docker file of sample code which i got from github. i wanted to create docker image of that file, and i want it to push it to azure container repository. How i can do that.

When i am running this command then i am getting this following error:

```
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1809                                              1.1s
 => CANCELED [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8                               1.1s
```

Docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS build

ARG CallSignalingPort=9441
ARG CallSignalingPort2=9442
ARG InstanceInternalPort=8445

COPY /src /src

WORKDIR /src
RUN nuget restore

WORKDIR /src/RecordingBot.Console
RUN msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutputPath=C:\app /p:Platform=x64


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1809
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command"]

ADD https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe /bot/VC_redist.x64.exe

COPY /scripts/entrypoint.cmd /bot
COPY /scripts/halt_termination.ps1 /bot
COPY --from=build /app /bot

WORKDIR /bot

RUN Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; \
    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = \
        [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; \
        iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

RUN choco install openssl.light -y

EXPOSE $InstanceInternalPort
EXPOSE $CallSignalingPort
EXPOSE $CallSignalingPort2

ENTRYPOINT [ "entrypoint.cmd" ]
```

This is the docker file which i got from sample code. i want docker image of this docker file. Please help us how we can create docker file?

Comment: Where i should run this command( rm  ~/.docker/config.json )

Comment: right now I am using a Linux container in docker. should I switch to a window container in docker ???

Comment: failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: no match for platform in manifest sha256:f585a495e54816ab869510758c57980d3ae44d4edf2552fc812ae24b327bf48d: not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.To build docker image from docker file use :`docker build .`
You can use -t parameter to tag the image with your desired name or else it will take some random name. Also .(dot) signifies location of dockerfile , assumming you have dockerfile in same location as pwd of your command prompt. Refer this for more https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

2. To upload docker image in azure you can follow the instructions from here :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-docker-cli?tabs=azure-cli